# Why does Clndr.destroy() fail in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, clndr.js

```
var myCalendar = $('#myCalendar').clndr();
myCalendar.destroy();
```

That's work great on Chrom but dons't work on ie. 
Ther's any solution to destroy clndr on ie ?

Comment: Possibly because the plugin doesn't support IE anymore? Is there any errors in the console?

Comment: Non ther's no errors in the console

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation for `Clndr` in case readers are unfamiliar with the plugin?

Comment: @Taplar https://github.com/kylestetz/CLNDR

Comment: What's your JQuery reference version? Have you ever checked the description at the end of [this article](https://github.com/kylestetz/CLNDR#internet-explorer-issues):If you're planning on supporting IE8 and below, you'll have to be careful about version dependencies. You'll need the jQuery 1.10.x branch for IE support, and if you're taking advantage of the constraints feature you'll need to use a version of moment.js <=2.1.0 or >=2.5.1.

Comment: Its not reproducible tested it in IE. The created instance is getting destroyed properly